# Win 7 setup stuck on "setup is starting"

Tags: windows-7, installation

I was doing business with my laptop when bluescreen came out and said your computer may be damaged and we are going to delete the threat.

When I tried to boot it back again computer said boot error status `0xc000000f`. Then I got installation disk and tried to install, but installation stucked on screen saying "setup is starting". Safe mode doesn't work nor the changing the disk.

I don't really want to change my hdd or any of computer parts.

How should I proceed with restoring the functionality of my laptop?

Comment: What sort of "business" have you been doing with your laptop before the issue? What is the model of your laptop? Can you find an example of the screen saying "your computer is damaged and we are going to delete the threat"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a clean install, try using G Parted to format and partition the disk. Be sure to save any files before portioning the disk.

After format is complete reinstall Windows.